# Getting error when using mongodb with php 7

Tags: mongodb, codeigniter

i upgrade to PHP 7 and when using MongoDB its giving me error. Its working fine in old system but when i change my system i install MongoDB and upgrade php5 to php7 its giving such error.

An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Error

Message: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern' not found

Filename: /opt/lampp/htdocs/chronicle/system/core/Loader.php

Line Number: 1284

Backtrace:

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/chronicle/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: Please note that, at least in the case of some Linux systems, each version of PHP may have its own directory contained in `/etc/php/`. You might find, for example, that you have both `/etc/php/5.0/` and `/etc/php/7.0/`. As a result, your `php.ini` files for the upgraded PHP version may not have the MongoDB extension enabled. You will need to explicitly add `extension=mongodb.so` to these new `php.ini` files if that line doesn't already exist. Please ensure that you have the extension enabled.

Comment: If you're using a Windows-based server, you will need to check the appropriate folder on windows and add `extension=php_mongodb.dll` to your `php.ini` files instead.